# How can I change Outlook default image?

Tags: 9.0-pie, outlook, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I have the application [Outlook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.outlook) on my Samsung Galaxy Note 8 and I have several accounts, but both adresses start with the same letter (see picture below).

[image: my two Outlook accounts]

I would like to know how to customize these icons so that I do not confuse the two accounts.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to set a profile photo to one of the accounts? In the end it does not have to be a real photo of you, just some image that then will be displayed in the app instead of the standard "M".

Comment: @Robert No I didn't because I didn't find a way to do this in the app, that's what I am asking actually, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Office 365 is a cloud service. It is totally irrelevant which client you use for changing the profile photo. Some clients may not support to set the profile photo, in such a case you have to use a different client, e.g. the web UI via chrome or your favorite web browser.

Comment: @Robert I changed my profile picture with chrome as you advised, but it didn't update on the app.